# Calling C# from native C++, without /clr or COM?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, mono, cross-platform

I have a class library written in C#, and I want to call it from a legacy native C++ application. The host application is truly native, compiled on Windows and Linux, and it’s a console application. So how can I make it call the C# class library, assuming using Microsoft .NET on Windows, and [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) on Linux?

I have looked at [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) and wrapping with [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interfaces on Windows, but is there a standard recognized solution that works cross platform? I.e., that is generic, works with both Microsoft .NET and Mono. A write-once-use-everywhere implementation.

Solutions should expose the full class interfaces from the C# domain to the C++ domain.

Similar questions focus only on the Windows solutions, for example -

[Call C# methods from C++ without using COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277809/call-c-methods-from-c-without-using-com)

Comment: You'd have to ask the mono guys if, and how, they have exported that.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this cross platform, I would recommend going with a 100% Mono approach.

Mono has a clean [Embedding API](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) which works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Good answer, embedding Mono on Windows not really what I was looking for also it all looks very manual. You would have to write a lot of boiler plate code to expose an full interface to a library, it looks time consuming and fragile, reminds me of JNI. I was wondering if there is some sort of automated way, like SWIG or just exposing a COM interface.

Comment: COM works well, but not so well on linux.  SWIG is only good for going the other way...  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

With .NET 5.0 (the successor of .NET Core) this is [now possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/#native-exports) to call C# from C++ in a cross-platform way without using Mono. Please see the solution explained [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/18174) using [DNNE](https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE) to generate a shared library and GCHandles to access C# objects.

With this you get a shared library that can be used from C or C++. Note that this will give a C-like API (no objects, like when using `extern C` in C++), in the future there may be tools like SWIG for C++ to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Please post the code inline. If not possible, please link directly to the code snippet instead of a github issue containing multiple comments.

Comment: @Gili here is a snippet demonstrating a C# interface that can be called using this method: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/18174#issuecomment-642124735 People should refer to the [DNNE documentation](https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE) for how to create a DLL. This is a very new feature (.NET 5.0 is still in beta) but as it was not mentioned anywhere on SO I assumed it would be ok to not have more inline content yet. Moreover the other answer was found helpful (+5) despite not having inlined code.

Comment: What is "DNNE" for? ".NET native exports"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I would guess like you: "Dot Net Native Export"