# How to call C# methods from C++ code on Linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux

I have some C# library - for the sake of simplicity say it has such code:

```
namespace space1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method1");
        }

        public static string Method2(string str1, string str2)
        {
            return str1 + " " + str2;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to call it from C++ code somehow. I've been looking around and have tried solutions but non of them were applicable for my case for following reasons:

- Use of Windows API - the program will run exclusively on Linux
- Use of Visual Studio libraries - the C++ program is to be compiled using `gcc` or `g++`
- No changes to the C# library can be made

So far I have not find anything that would meet all requirements. Rewriting the library is out of the question (there could be some wrapper library thou). I would also like to avoid having additional program - like C++ code starting a process and feeding arguments via `stdin`, pipes or TCP.

Comment: `C#` cannot run on linux if you do not change it and compile as `.netcore` period. The only other possible solution is to run it in a hosted process on a windows machine and TCP to it.

Comment: The library shown has been compiled and tested on `Mono` runtime so, yeah - I know that

Comment: You would need to use the [Hosting apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting) I can't turn this into an answer as I don't have enough experience with them to give pointers.

Comment: This is now possible with .NET 5.0, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203205/4669135