#  cannot convert parameter 1 from  'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'CvCapture **'

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I am capturing a video frame as follows

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture("PATH");
```

I can read the video and process it. Everything works fine. But when I try to release the capture

```
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
```

I get

```
error C2664: 'cvReleaseCapture' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'CvCapture **'
          with
          [
              Type=CvCapture *
          ]
          Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type
```

The function is inside a class.

```
public ref class Locator
```

and I am calling it from the main

Locator r;

Before I added it **public ref ** to *class locator* it was not giving me any error.

Any ideas for fixing it? It was working fine before switching to c++-cli.

I think it is related to some heap problem, items on the heap can be moved as a result of garbage collection. In order to send a pointer to a native method/function, you need to “pin” the pointer for the duration of the call, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Updated:

That fixed it.

```
pin_ptr<CvCapture*> p;
p = &capture;
cvReleaseCapture( p );
```

Comment: You need to call `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` to clean up the string that StringToHGlobalAnsi creates. See this answer for sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5667246/480937

Comment: How does that affect capture?

Comment: I edited the question because even if I give it the path directly it still gives me the same error

Comment: It doesn't affect capture, so I didn't enter it as an answer, but it is a memory leak that affects your program.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll fix that leak.

Comment: Have you tried pin_ptr?  Something like `pin_ptr<CvCapture> pCapture = &capture`

Comment: pin_ptr looks like correct solution, I think it should be pin_ptr<CvCapture*>

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. But I wish I saw your answer before cause I fixed it on my own but thanks.

Comment: @AlexFarber - Yes you are correct, the `pin_ptr<CvCapture*>` is required.

Comment: @ChrisO it seems that you should add that tip as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Adding as answer, thanks to @AlexFarber for the correction)

Have you tried pin_ptr? Something like:

```
pin_ptr<CvCapture*> pCapture = &capture;
```